# Could Adam eat of the forbidden fruit more than once?

Tags: genesis-bereishith

The way Genesis is structured it is not clear if Adam ate of the tree more then once?

> Adam is disobedient, because he ate fruit from the forbidden tree

If Adam was to eat of the tree the second time would it be a sin?

Comment: Can you quote the  passuk the passuk in its original Hebrew and bring the source? It will make it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

We differentiate between two types of Mitzvos - one-time commandments and "all-time" Mitzvos. That's how Rambam codified that in Sefer Hamitzvos ([Shoresh 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.3?lang=bi), couldn't find in English):

> שאין ראוי למנות מצות שאין נוהגות לדורות. (We don't count Mitzvos that don't last forever).

Many commandments in the Torah, that G-d commanded our forefathers (and earlier) were one-time commandments, e.g. the commandment to Avraham to sacrifice Itzhak, or the order of actions on the night of the Exodus - many of them were relevant only to that night.

It appears that the prohibition of not eating from the tree was a one-time commandment because it changes Adam's essence. And therefore it can not be "transgressed" once again. Similarly, there's no purity after purity and impurity after impurity. Once you cross the line, you're there.

Comment: How do you know that  the prohibition of not eating from the tree was a one-time commandment?

Comment: @JoeHoward SImple, it's not on the list of the 613 Mitzvos!

Comment: Perhaps it's not counted as part of the 613 because only 2 people had that commandment?

Comment: @JoeHoward Yaakov was commanded alone on Gid Haneshe and it does not reappear after Matan Torah but we still don't eat it.

Comment: have you forgotten the verse:  (gen. 33,34) Therefore the children of Israel eat not the sinew of the thigh-vein which is upon the hollow of the thigh, unto this day; because he touched the hollow of Jacob's thigh, even in the sinew of the thigh-vein.  ?

Comment: @JoeHoward **After** Matan Torah.

Comment: "unto this day" is referring to after Matan Torah.

Comment: @JoeHoward OK you won with Gid Haneshe.

Answer (score 0):

Is it illegal to rob a bank? If the bank robber robs the bank again, is the second time illegal too?

On a side note: Not sure what the relevance your comparison between Adam and Jesus is?

Comment: The difference is that in the question, the reason for the issur doesn’t exist anymore, but in your answer, the answer does.

Comment: @joe Howard when did the Q. mention Jesus?

Comment: @Turk Hill the answer was written before the question was edited

Comment: @Loani In what manner did it compare Jesus and Moshe?

Comment: @Loani my does the reason for the issur not exist, did G-d at some point allow eating from the tree?

Comment: @TurkHill click on "edited n minutes ago".

Comment: @JoeHoward I see. Jesus was not obedient. He didn't want to go to the cross. That is a bad comparison. What Christians don't get is that it was good (in their minds) that we killed Jesus because who would have saved their souls? Instead, they thank us with blood. Thankfully, many Christians are becoming a commodity to Israel today and the Second Vatican admits that we never killed him. Christians are irrational! G-d is One.